# Date grouping in a simple sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need some help with a SQL query. I have a table in a SQL server database with three fields. Field1, Field2 and DateField. I want to do a count of how many records at any given time are returned where Field1 matches a set variable, Field2 matches a set variable, and the DateField is on the same day (24 hr day from 12:00am - 23:59pm)

```
select count(*)
from TableA
where Field1 = 'A'
and Field2 = 'B'
and DateField = TODAY
```

I need help with the date grouping. Any help would be appreciate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a nutshell:

```
and DateField >= TODAY and DateField < TOMORROW
```

specifically:

```
and DateField >= cast(current_timestamp as date) and DateField < cast(dateadd(dd, 1, current_timestamp) as date)
```

You can also use `BETWEEN`, but I prefer the exclusive upper bound. If find that approach less prone to mistakes, such as using `11:59pm` as the end time and leaving records from `23:59.001` to `23:59.997` without a home, or matching on records that actually fall on midnight tomorrow.

Comment: `and DateField >= TODAY and DateField < TOMORROW` is equivalent to `and DateField = TODAY`, isn't it?

Comment: @Horaciux only if the field is a date type with no time component. In SQL, if you compare a date with a date time it converts the former to the latter and compares the values as if the time is midnight.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
select count(*)
from TableA
where Field1 = 'A' and Field2 = 'B' and
      DateField = cast(getdate() as date);
```

Comment: The mention of `24hr day from 12:00am - 23:59pm` makes me worry he actually has a `DateTime` column, in which case this answer is wrong.

Comment: Joel is correct... this is kind of what I need, but it would have to be an exact datetime match... and it wont be.... Is it possible to distill it down to just the date and not datetime? I dont really care what time it is set to... just so long as its on the same day